# Bootstrap Navbar <li> Spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok I have looked all over the css and can't seem to figure out what is determining the width between the top level links on my navbar. I need to make them just barely smaller so when it adjust for a sub 900px screen it doesn't turn it into a 2 row navbar instead of the usual 1 row.

I tried something like navbar > li but had no success getting them to move. But to no avail so I am asking

Thank You here is my navbar code

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <!-- Wrap the .navbar in .container to center it within the absolutely positioned parent. -->
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 1: Button for triggering responsive navbar (not covered in tutorial). Include responsive CSS to utilize. -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="index.html">PC3</a>
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 2: Place all navbar contents you want collapsed withing .navbar-collapse.collapse. -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">

                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us <b class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="core.html">Core values</a></li>
                    <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="know.html">How To Know God</a></li>
                 <li><a href="vol.html">Volunteering</a></li>

                 <li><a href="giving.html">Giving</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Directions & Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Adult Ministries<b class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="adtov.html">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="adtov.html#pst">Personal Spiritual Trainer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="adtov.html#care">Care Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="adtov.html#hosp">Hospitality team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="adtov.html#int">Intercessory Prayer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="adtov.html#womens">Women's Ministry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="amp.html">Amplified Worship</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sermons.html">Sermons</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Student Ministries<b class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="stuov.html">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="stuov.html#adult">Just For Parents</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PC Kids<b class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="kidov.html">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kidvid.html">Videos</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Life Groups<b class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="groups.html">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="groups.html#leaders">Leaders & Group Info</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                 <li><a href="missions.html">Missions</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->

      </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-wrapper -->
```

[image: broken nav]

Comment: We'll need to see some CSS or a link or something...HTML is just markup, it doesn't reflect the styling.

Comment: Also, try some DOM analysis tools - in Chrome there's "Inspect Element" on right click, in Firefox there's Firebug, etc.  You can see what style classes are affecting the element pretty easily, and it's a useful tool for the future (not just this question).

Comment: actually I found it looks like i missed the padding for the .inner object, thank you for the suggestion tho, reminded me to use dreamweavers css tools

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was looking for, didn't look in the second css, which has the responsive css and didn't edit the padding for the .inner class.

That was my fault thank you tho